# Rails 5, has_many relationship with custom name test failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am having trouble with an `has_many` relationship with custom name in Rails 5.1

I have a domain model with users, items from a catalogue, and favourites. A user can have many favourite items.

A favourite can have additional items as well.

I'm doing this as a learning exercise on modifying exisiting apps, so I've added each relationship with a dedicated migration:

```
class AddUserToFavourite < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :favourites, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class AddItemToFavourite < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :favourites, :item, foreign_key: true
  end
end

class AddAdditionalItemsToFavourite < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :favourites, :additional_item, foreign_key: { to_table: :items }
  end
end
```

The resulting schema is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170921111049) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "favourites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.bigint "additional_item_id"
    t.index ["additional_item_id"], name: "index_favourites_on_additional_item_id"
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_favourites_on_item_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_favourites_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "favourites", "items"
  add_foreign_key "favourites", "items", column: "additional_item_id"
  add_foreign_key "favourites", "users"
end
```

This is how my models look like:

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favourites
end

# item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :additional_item, class_name: 'Favourite', optional: true
end

# favourite.rb
class Favourite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  has_many :additional_items, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: 'additional_item_id'
end
```

This is my spec for `Favourite`:

```
# favourite_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Favourite, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should belong_to :item }
  it { should have_many(:additional_items).with_foreign_key('additional_item_id') }

  it 'can be created with no additional items' do
    expect(Favourite.create!(name: 'Name', user: User.create!, item: Item.create!).additional_items).to be_empty
  end
end
```

If I run the tests I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column items.additional_item_id does not exist
       LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."additional_item...
                                                   ^
       : SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE "items"."additional_item_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

I understand what the error means. The table `items` doesn't have an `additional_item_id` column. You can see it in the schema as well.

What I don't understand is why should it be there? Isn't having the foreign key on the Favourites table enough?

Am I doing something wrong in how I wrote the migration or the relationships in the models?

I am very rusty with Rails and DB theory and design, so feel free to point out any silly mistake that I've made. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The issue was in how I was trying to model the relationship between the favourite and its additional items. *I had to refresh up my DB knowledge a bit...*

The fact that a favourite can have many items in the relationship called `additional_items` does not imply that `has_many` is the right way to describe such relationship when defining the model.

In particular, `has_many` defines the "one" side of a [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)).

My additional items relationship is instead a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)). Yes, one favourite can have many additional items, but at the same time one item can be part of the additional items set of many favourites.

Rails offers to ways to describe many-to-many relationships, [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

In my case `has_and_belogns_to_many` was the most appropriate choice, as per what suggested in the [Rails guide on choosing between the two options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

What I did then was:

**1.** Revert the commits with the migration adding the reference to `items` from `favourite`, the relative schema update, and the `has_many` definition in the `Favourite` model.

**2.** Drop the database, `bundle exec rake db:drop`

**3.** Generate a new migration to add a *join table* to represent the many-to-many association:

```
class CreateFavouritesAdditionalItemsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :favourites, :items, table_name: 'additional_items_favourites'
  end
end
```

**4.** Update the spec for the `Favourite` model:

```
require 'rails_helper'require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Favourite, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should belong_to :item }
  it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:additional_items) }

  # These tests here are just for me to ensure I configured things properly.
  # In a real app you wouldn't need to do this because there would be other
  # tests that implicitly act on how the association is setup.
  it 'can be created without additional items' do
    expect(Favourite.create!(user: User.create!, item: Item.create!).additional_items).to be_empty
  end

  it 'can be updated adding additional items' do
    f = Favourite.create!(user: User.create!, item: Item.create!)
    item1 = Item.create!(description: 'foo')
    item2 = Item.create!(description: 'bar')
    f.additional_items << [item1, item2]

    expect(f.additional_items.length).to eq 2
    expect(f.additional_items).to include item1
    expect(f.additional_items).to include item2
  end
end
```

**5.** Implement the actual association in `Faovurite`:

```
class Favourite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  has_and_belongs_to_many :additional_items,
    join_table: 'additional_items_favourites',
    association_foreign_key: 'item_id',
    class_name: 'Item'
end
```

Notice how because of the custom name of the association, the name of the `join_table` and the `class_name` of the associated model has to be specified, as ActiveRecord would otherwise have inferred them from `:additional_items`, failing to find such table and class.

I'm pleased to say that it was not necessary to specify neither the `foreign_key` nor the `association_foreign_key`, `favourite_id` and `item_id` respectively, as they can be inferred from the class name.